# Speed up nested loops and bitwise operations with Alea GPU

Tags: c#, cuda, aleagpu

I'm trying to use Alea to speed up a program I'm working on but I need some help.

What I need to do is a lot of bitcount and bitwise operations with values stored in two arrays.

For each element of my first array I have to do a bitwise & operation with each element of my second array, then count the bits set to 1 of the & result.

If the result is greater than/equal to a certain value I need to exit the inner for and go to the next element of my first array.

The first array is usually a big one, with millions of elements, the second one is usually less than 200.000 elements.

Trying to do all these operations in parallel, here is my code:

```
[GpuManaged]
private long[] Check(long[] arr1, long[] arr2, int limit)
{
    Gpu.FreeAllImplicitMemory(true);
    var gpu = Gpu.Default;
    long[] result = new long[arr1.Length];
    gpu.For(0, arr1.Length, i =>
    {
        bool found = false;
        long b = arr1[i];
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < arr2.Length; i2++)
        {
            if (LibDevice.__nv_popcll(b & arr2[i2]) >= limit)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            result[i] = b;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

This works as expected but is just a little faster than my version running in parallel on a quad core CPU.

I'm certainly missing something here, it's my very first attempt to write GPU code.

By the way, my NVIDIA is a GeForce GT 740M.

**EDIT**

The following code is 2x faster than the previous one, at least on my PC. Many thanks to Michael Randall for pointing me in the right direction.

```
private static int[] CheckWithKernel(Gpu gpu, int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int limit)
{
    var lp = new LaunchParam(16, 256);
    var result = new int[arr1.Length];
    try
    {
        using (var dArr1 = gpu.AllocateDevice(arr1))
        using (var dArr2 = gpu.AllocateDevice(arr2))
        using (var dResult = gpu.AllocateDevice<int>(arr1.Length))
        {
            gpu.Launch(Kernel, lp, arr1.Length, arr2.Length, dArr1.Ptr, dArr2.Ptr, dResult.Ptr, limit);
            Gpu.Copy(dResult, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Gpu.Free(arr1);
        Gpu.Free(arr2);
        Gpu.Free(result);
    }
}

private static void Kernel(int a1, int a2, deviceptr<int> arr1, deviceptr<int> arr2, deviceptr<int> arr3, int limit)
{
    var iinit = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    var istep = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    for (var i = iinit; i < a1; i += istep)
    {
        bool found = false;
        int b = arr1[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < a2; j++)
        {
            if (LibDevice.__nv_popcll(b & arr2[j]) >= limit)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            arr3[i] = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a 740M, I certainly wouldn't expect it to be so much faster than a quad core

Comment: Are you referencing Alea.Fody nuget package?

Comment: Anyway, I think @CamiloTerevinto is right. Your code runs 50 times faster on my GPU than on my 4 (8 virtual) core CPU with naive CPU implementation (while naive - it still eats 100% of my CPU). Worth also including your CPU implementation for comparision.

Comment: @Evk yes, Alea.Fody is working correctly, thank you for trying to help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

It seems pinning wont work with GCHandle.Alloc()

However the point of this answer is you will get a much greater performance gain out of direct memory access.

http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/advanced_features_csharp.html

**Directly Working with Device Memory**

> Device memory provides even more flexibility as it also allows all
>   kind of pointer arithmetics. Device memory is allocated with

```
Memory<T> Gpu.AllocateDevice<T>(int length)
Memory<T> Gpu.AllocateDevice<T>(T[] array)
```

> The first overload creates a device memory object for the specified
>   type `T` and length on the selected GPU. The second one allocates
>   storage on the GPU and copies the .NET array into it. Both return a
>   `Memory<T>` object, which implements `IDisposable` and can therefore
>   support the using syntax which ensures proper disposal once the
>   `Memory<T>` object goes out of scope. `A Memory<T>` object has properties
>   to determine the length, the GPU or the device on which it lives. The 
>   `Memory<T>.Ptr` property returns a `deviceptr<T>`, which can be used in
>   GPU code to access the actual data or to perform pointer arithmetics.
>   The following example illustrates a simple use case of device
>   pointers. The kernel only operates on part of the data, defined by an
>   offset.

```
using (var dArg1 = gpu.AllocateDevice(arg1))
using (var dArg2 = gpu.AllocateDevice(arg2))
using (var dOutput = gpu.AllocateDevice<int>(Length/2))
{           
    // pointer arithmetics to access subset of data
    gpu.Launch(Kernel, lp, dOutput.Length, dOutput.Ptr, dArg1.Ptr + Length/2, dArg2.Ptr + Length / 2);

    var result = dOutput.ToArray();

    var expected = arg1.Skip(Length/2).Zip(arg2.Skip(Length/2), (x, y) => x + y);

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

## Original Answer

Disregarding the logic going on, or how relevant this is to GPU code. However you could compliment your *Parallel* routine and possibly speed things up by by *Pinning* your *Arrays* in memory with [`GCHandle.Alloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`GCHandleType.Pinned`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y4ak54(v=vs.110).aspx) flag and using *Direct Pointer* access (if you can run [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index) code)

> **Notes**
>
> - You will cop a hit from pinning the memory, however for large arrays you can realize a lot of performance from direct access*
> - You will have to mark your assembly unsafe in Build Properties*
> - This is obviously untested and just an example*
> - You could used fixed, however the Parallel Lambda makes it fiddlier

**Example**

```
private unsafe long[] Check(long[] arr1, long[] arr2, int limit)
{   
   Gpu.FreeAllImplicitMemory(true);
   var gpu = Gpu.Default;    
   var result = new long[arr1.Length];

   // Create some pinned memory
   var resultHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   var arr2Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   var arr1Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);

   // Get the addresses
   var resultPtr = (int*)resultHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
   var arr2Ptr = (int*)arr2Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
   var arr1Ptr = (int*)arr2Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();

   // I hate nasty lambda statements. I always find local methods easier to read.    
   void Workload(int i)
   {
      var found = false;    
      var b = *(arr1Ptr + i);

      for (var j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++)
      {
         if (LibDevice.__nv_popcll(b & *(arr2Ptr + j)) >= limit)
         {
            found = true;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (!found)
      {
         *(resultPtr + i) = b;
      }
   }

   try
   {
      gpu.For(0, arr1.Length, i => Workload(i));
   }
   finally 
   {
      // Make sure we free resources
      arr1Handle.Free();
      arr2Handle.Free();
      resultHandle.Free();
   } 
   return result;    
}
```

---

## Additional Resources

[GCHandle.Alloc Method (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A new GCHandle that protects the object from garbage collection. This
>   GCHandle must be released with Free when it is no longer needed.

[GCHandleType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y4ak54(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Pinned**    : This handle type is similar to Normal, but allows the address of the pinned object to be taken. This prevents the garbage
>   collector from moving the object and hence undermines the efficiency
>   of the garbage collector. Use the Free method to free the allocated
>   handle as soon as possible.

[Unsafe Code and Pointers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index)

> In the common language runtime (CLR), unsafe code is referred to as
>   unverifiable code. Unsafe code in C# is not necessarily dangerous; it
>   is just code whose safety cannot be verified by the CLR. The CLR will
>   therefore only execute unsafe code if it is in a fully trusted
>   assembly. If you use unsafe code, it is your responsibility to ensure
>   that your code does not introduce security risks or pointer errors.

- A note, there has since been an update, this:

> http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/advanced_features_csharp.html

is now this:

> http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_4/doc/advanced_features_csharp.html

some of the samples and info have changed or moved in release 3.0.4.

Comment: No i didn't, i am just giving a suggestion, to pin and access direct

Comment: @evk i guess i can see problems there already with the `int*` and the `long`, is this is what you are alluding to?

Comment: Well I just tried to run it and it "doesn't work" that is - throws exception that (as I understand), pointer types are not supported by that Alea library.

Comment: @Evk seems there is pointer access though http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/advanced_features_csharp.html

Comment: Well I see this library for the first time myself, so cannot draw any conclusions, but as I said - your code as is does not work, and it _seems_ to be because of pointer types. Maybe it can be fixed, maybe not - not sure.